# Get Schema object from TCM URI

Tags: 2011, core-service

I have TCM URI of a Schema, is there any way to get the Schema object from that?

I have tried some code but that only returns the XML of the Schema, I don't know how I can convert it to the Schema object. If I get the Schema object then I can access `Schema.NamespaceUri` to get the UUID of that Schema.

I am trying the following code but, it only returns the Schema XML.

```
var resultXml = client.GetListXml(
        publicationId, 
        new RepositoryItemsFilterData 
        {
            ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Schema }, 
            Recursive=true 
        }
    ).Elements().Where(schemaElem => schemaElem.Attribute("ID").Value==schemaID);
```

When I use the following method, it throws an error

```
var filter = new RepositoryItemsFilterData
        {
            SchemaPurposes = new[] { SchemaPurpose.Metadata },
            Recursive = true,
            ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Schema }
        };

var result = client.GetList(schemaID, filter);
```

> Unexpected list type:
>
> Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.RepositoryItemsFilterData.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Coreservices try this.

```
SchemaData schema = (SchemaData)client.Read("Your Id", new ReadOptions());
```

Comment: worked, thank you. If i understand correctly, I can use read method to get information of any object by passing TCM ID in the parameter, Right?

Comment: right, it will return a IdentifiableObjectData instance, IdentifiableObjectData is the base class for all the tridion items so you need to cast it.

Comment: Indeed `CoreServiceClient.Read` is going to return info about any item in Tridion with a `TcmUri` given that the user doing the operation has necessary permission.